# Oracle ASH report - Top SQL with Top Row Sources

Tags: oracle

I am new to oracle database. I am using oracle 19c version. I generated an ASH report and there is a section for top row sources for each sql_id. What does "Row Source Not Available" mean in the report and why information is not displayed for specific statements? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the cursor is not closed.